# Mediawiki, phpMyAdmin, SQL help with values of type BLOB and TINY BLOB

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, blob, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki site and access to it's SQL database via phpMyAdmin (a tool I am not at all familiar with)

I am interested in checking/confirming and maybe updating the email of a user's account that needs to be changed. When I query the account, the value is displayed simply as its type- "BLOB"

How can I view the value in this column?

Similarly, I'd like to see a list of IPs from a certain time frame, but they are all stored as TINY BLOB and will not display via phpMyAdmin. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

over the records that you see in brows tab you have

`option`

click over it and set

`Show BLOB contents`

then click go